# How to make queries from multiple models in a single view

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am working on a school placement system and I have multiple models to query from. First I want to loop through the students' list and check if the two student's ID in the profile and result model match. Then I will check if the student has passed and then place the student.

I am using Django 2.2.1. I did a lot of search but to no avail. Below are some of my codes.

## Here is my student model.

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Extra Fields
    student_ID = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    middle_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STUDENT_GENDER_CHOICES)
    disability = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=STUDENT_DISABILITY_CHOICES)
    locality = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=STUDENT_LOCALITY_CHOICES)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photos', blank=True, default='profile_photos/default.svg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

## This is my result upload model

```
class StudentResultsUpload(models.Model):
    student_ID = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    english = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    mathematics = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    integrated_Science = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    social_Studies = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    basic_Design_Technology = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    home_Economics = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ghanaian_Language = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    french = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
```

## This is my school selection model.

## NB: I removed the multiple school models and put everything in one model.

```
class SchoolSelection(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    school_One = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    program_One = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    residential_Status_One = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=RESIDENTIAL_STATUS_CHOICES)

    school_Two = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    program_Two = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    residential_Status_Two = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=RESIDENTIAL_STATUS_CHOICES)

    school_Three = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    program_Three = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    residential_Status_Three = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=RESIDENTIAL_STATUS_CHOICES)

    school_Four = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    program_Four = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    residential_Status_Four = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=RESIDENTIAL_STATUS_CHOICES)

    school_Five = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    program_Five = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    residential_Status_Five = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=RESIDENTIAL_STATUS_CHOICES)
```

## And this is my views.py for placement.

```
def placement(request):
    profile = StudentProfile.objects.all()
    place = StudentResultsUpload.objects.all()
    schools = SchoolSelection.objects.all()


    placements = []
    for candidate in profile:
        for pl in place:

            if candidate.student_ID == pl.student_ID:
                if (pl.english >= 50 and pl.mathematics >= 50 and pl.integrated_Science >= 50 and pl.social_Studies >= 50):

                    raw_score = (pl.english + pl.mathematics + pl.integrated_Science + pl.social_Studies + pl.basic_Design_Technology + pl.home_Economics)
                    for school in schools:
                        if raw_score >= 480:
                            place_me = school.school_One
                        elif raw_score >= 420:
                            place_me = school.school_Two
                        elif raw_score >= 360:
                            place_me = school.school_Three
                        elif raw_score >= 300:
                            place_me = school.school_Four
                        else:
                            place_me = school.school_Five

                        placements.append({'student': candidate, 'school': place_me})
                    return render(request, 'schools/placement.html', {'place_me': placements})

                else:
                    return HttpResponse("Sorry, you did not qualify for placement.")
```

## Here is my placement.html file

```
<div class="container">
<p id="success">
    Placement Here.
</p>
{% for placement in place_me %}
    Stdudent ID: {{ placement.student.student_ID }}<br>
    Stdudent username: {{ placement.student.user }}<br>
    Stdudent gender: {{ placement.student.gender }}<br>
    School: {{ placement.school }}<br><br>

{% endfor %}
</div>
```

But when I run it, it is not iterating properly through all the students in the system. It is only retaining multiple instances of one student but it will pick the schools of other students and display for the one student that it is returning its multiple instances.

Comment: You shouldn't be iterating at all like that. It's very inefficient. You should define foreign keys to link the models, and follow them directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) indicated you should use Foreign Keys to associate different models. A refactoring of your code should be something like the codes below.

## The StudentResultsUpload model

```
class StudentResultsUpload(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    english = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    mathematics = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    integrated_Science = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    social_Studies = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    basic_Design_Technology = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    home_Economics = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ghanaian_Language = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    french = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
```

## The SchoolSelectionOne model

```
class SchoolSelectionOne(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name_of_School = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    program = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    residential_Status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=RESIDENTIAL_STATUS_CHOICES
```

## The placement function

```
def placement(request):
    profiles = StudentProfile.objects.all()
    uploads = StudentResultsUpload.objects.all()
    school_one = SchoolSelectionOne.objects.all()
    school_two = SchoolSelectionTwo.objects.all()
    school_three = SchoolSelectionThree.objects.all()
    school_four = SchoolSelectionFour.objects.all()
    school_five = SchoolSelectionFive.objects.all()

    profile_dicts = []
    for profile in profiles:
        try:
            upload = [u for u in uploads if u.student.pk == profile.pk][0]
            one = [s for s in school_one if s.student.pk == profile.pk][0]
            two = [s for s in school_two if s.student.pk == profile.pk][0]
            three = [s for s in school_three if s.student.pk == profile.pk][0]
            four = [s for s in school_four if s.student.pk == profile.pk][0]
            five = [s for s in school_five if s.student.pk == profile.pk][0]
        except (AttributeError, IndexError):
            continue

        profile_dicts.append({
            'upload': upload,
            'school_one': one,
            'school_two': two,
            'school_three': three,
            'school_four': four,
            'school_five': five
        })

    place_me_list = []
    for profile in profile_dicts:
        upload = profile['upload']

        if (
                upload.english >= 50 and
                upload.mathematics >= 50 and
                upload.integrated_Science >= 50 and
                upload.social_Studies >= 50
        ):
            raw_score = (
                upload.english +
                upload.mathematics +
                upload.integrated_Science +
                upload.social_Studies +
                upload.basic_Design_Technology +
                upload.home_Economics
            )

            if raw_score >= 480:
                place_me = profile['school_one']
            elif raw_score >= 420:
                place_me = profile['school_two']
            elif raw_score >= 360:
                place_me = profile['school_three']
            elif raw_score >= 300:
                place_me = profile['school_four']
            else:
                place_me = profile['school_five']

            place_me_list.append(place_me)

    return render(request, 'schools/placements.html', {'place_me': place_me_list})
```

In placement function to avoid using the nested for I firstly found the desired information for each candidate (supposing that each one is associated with schools and upload models) and then I made the calculations.

Comment: Thank you so much, boss. But when I tried it threw back this error: AttributeError at /schools/placement/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pk'

Comment: You are welcome @john, but this means that any of your StudentResultsUpload or SchoolSelection instances have not value for student field. So you should set this field for all these instances or use a try except for AttributeError and pass this exception.

Comment: Please, I am very much grateful for your help. But when I run the updated code again it gave me another error: UnboundLocalError at /schools/placement/
local variable 'upload' referenced before assignment. It was referring to this part of the code profile_dicts.append({
            'upload': upload,. Please help me.

Comment: Please, is can you provide a way for me to contact you personally so that you help me out. This is my final year project and that part of the code is just giving me a headache. Deadline for submission is just a week away from today. Please help me

Comment: theomeli, please I am very sorry for disturbing you so much but I need help. Because of the way the code is giving me so much trouble, I made some changes to see how it will work but it is not giving me the desired output still. Please take a look at it and help me fix it. I am very sorry for the disturbance.

Comment: john which is the output you get? I don't know what do you want to fix, help me to help you

Comment: Please this is the output I get: Placement Here.

Stdudent ID: 1234567890
Stdudent username: test
Stdudent gender: male
School: NAVASCO


Stdudent ID: 1234567890
Stdudent username: test
Stdudent gender: male
School: ABSCO

Stdudent ID: 1234567890
Stdudent username: test
Stdudent gender: male
School: ABETIFI
I am testing with only 3 students but that is what I get. It looks like the for loop is not looping through correctly. I will be very much grateful if you will help me.

Comment: The same student details is just repeating instead of the other students.

Comment: John you have to make another view to fetch a single student, I changed the code to get a list of students in a placements html file. And please accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you so so much @theomeli. It finally worked for me. I don't know what I would have done without your help. God richly bless you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @theomeli. I have just accepted your answer.  I'm so much grateful.

Answer (score 0):

On these two lines

```
for candidate in profile:
    if profile.student_ID == place.student_ID:
```

you are indicating you want to use `candidate` as the variable name inside the loop, so the second line should probably read `if candidate.student_ID` instead of `if profile.student_ID`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I corrected that but when i run it again it throws the same error 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'student_ID'

Answer (score 0):

`place` is a queryset. so must be iterate it.

try this code:

```
def placement(request):
    profile = StudentProfile.objects.all()
    place = StudentResultsUpload.objects.all()
    school_one = SchoolSelectionOne.objects.all()
    school_two = SchoolSelectionTwo.objects.all()
    school_three = SchoolSelectionThree.objects.all()
    school_four = SchoolSelectionFour.objects.all()
    school_five = SchoolSelectionFive.objects.all()

    placements = []
    for candidate in profile:
        for pl in place:
            if candidate.student_ID == pl.student_ID:
                if (pl.english >= 50 and pl.mathematics >= 50 and pl.integrated_Science >= 50 and pl.social_Studies >= 50):
                    raw_score = (pl.english + pl.mathematics + pl.integrated_Science + pl.social_Studies + pl.basic_Design_Technology + pl.home_Economics)

                    if raw_score >= 480:
                        place_me = school_one
                    elif raw_score >= 420:
                        place_me = school_two
                    elif raw_score >= 360:
                        place_me = school_three
                    elif raw_score >= 300:
                        place_me = school_four
                    else:
                        place_me = school_five

                    placements.append({'student': candidate, 'school': place_me})
    return render(request, 'schools/placement.html', {'place_me': placements})
```

placement.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <p id="success">
        Placement Here.
    </p>
    {% for placement in place_me %}
        Stdudent Id: {{ placement.student.student_ID }}
        Stdudent middle name: {{ placement.student.middle_Name }}
        Stdudent gender: {{ placement.student.gender }}

        Placements:
            {% for school in placement.school %}
                {{ school }}
            {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @katoozi but when I tried, it threw back the same error message; AttributeError at /schools/placement/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'student_ID'

Comment: Thank you, boss. I updated the code and now it does not throw the error again but it is not giving me the desired output. When I run it, it is only returning the first choice schools for all the students no matter the raw score.

Comment: I don't know if it is because of the zip method I called on the schools' list. Please help.

Comment: The result is still the same boss. Maybe you should take a look at my placement.html code ```<div class="container">
        <p id="success">Placement Here.</p>
        {% for placement in place_me %}
            {{ placement }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>```

Comment: describe what you wan to do ?

Comment: Please, after checking the conditions and calculating the raw scores of each student I want to place them in the school they have qualified for based on their raw score. But what I noticed is the code is not looping through every student's raw score to place them. And also the school's list is not being looped through properly. Please help me with this.

Comment: @john tray again/

Comment: Thank you so much katoozi, but when I tried it gave me all the schools in the school_one folder and all the schools in the school_two folder.

Comment: But I am so much grateful for how you are committed to helping me. God bless you.

Comment: Hello, please help me. This is my final year project and the deadline for submission is just a week away from today. Thank you.

Comment: katoozi, please I made some changes to the code. Please look at it and help me fix it. Thank you.